# Authorize.net payment gateway not working in WooCommerce

Tags: php, authorize.net

I am developing woocommerce project . I used Authorize.net payment gateway plugin for that.

payment and order placings are working fine.But after get payment that url not redirect to success page .
I want show order info after payment completed. May be my x_relay_url is wrong.

I don't know how to give that .please tell me One example url for that and solve this problem to me...

after payment completed it's showing like this message..

```
                               An error occurred while trying to report this 
  transaction to the merchant. An e-mail has been sent to the merchant informing them  
 of the    error. The following is the result of the attempt to charge your credit card. 

  This transaction has been approved.
 It is advisable for you to contact the merchant to verify that you will receive the  
   product or service.
```

NOTE: IT IS IN TEST MODE.

thanks & regards..

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurs when the payment gateway is unable to POST to the relay response URL you configured.  Since the POST is coming from Authorize.Net, the URL must be publicly available.

Also, if you are testing in the sandbox, you should not send transactions in Test Mode.  Transactions submitted with test mode only confirm if the API Login and Transaction Key are correct, and returns OK but does not actually process and store a transaction.